# 'scope' keyword in Knockout 'data-bind'

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js, scope, magento2

I found the following code in Magento 2 HTML:

`<div id="cart-totals" class="cart-totals" data-bind="scope:'block-totals'">`

Magento 2 uses Knockout on frontend but I cannot found in Knockout docs what does keyword "scope" mean in this context. Is it a Magento 2 feature?

Comment: Searching for "magento scope binding" returns this http://magento-quickies.alanstorm.com/post/145884289995/magento-2-knockoutjs-viewmodels-and-scope which also led me to find out that there's a magento site on SE https://magento.stackexchange.com/ you'd be surprised what you can find through a simple search.

Answer (score 9):

Your assumption is right, the `scope` binding is not build-in into knockout, but a magento feature.

From what I understood, magento uses the `applyBindings` function from knockout without assigning a viewmodel. The `scope` binding then looks for and loads a registered viewmodel (in this case: `'block-totals'`) and applies this to the DOM node, where you have your `scope` binding.

For detailed information, have a look here (and give the guy some credit, too :))

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/120447/how-does-magento-2-apply-knockoutjs-bindings

http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_knockoutjs_integration/